# Custom fields in universal login in Auth0

Tags: auth0

Do I have to use Lock in `Auth0` if I want to add first and last name fields in the sign up form or can I have these additional fields in my sign up through Universal Login as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should be able to edit the [hosted login page](https://manage.auth0.com/#/login_page) in your dashboard and add additional fields. It would look something like:

```
var lock = new Auth0Lock(config.clientID, config.auth0Domain, {
...
additionalSignUpFields: [{  
    name: "fullname", 
    placeholder: "Full name"
     }] ,
... 
});
```

When your users sign up the custom fields will be part of the `user_metadata`. The limitations are listed here (like the field must be a string, it cannot be more than 500 characters, etc.) : https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/custom-signup#custom-fields-limitations

Hope that helps!